# Probability statistics exercise, with not enough data?

Tags: probability, self-study

I have a question connected with this exercise. In question a) I am supposed to calculate the probability using this formula $P(A \text{ and } B)=P(A) \times P(B|A)$. I think there is not enough data. Can anybody please help me?

In March 2005, the Australian government announced that an extra 450 troops would be sent to Iraq. A special Morgan poll was conducted to evaluate public opinion on Australia’s military presence in Iraq in the middle of March 2005 using an Australia-wide representative sample. It was found that 0,85 % of the respondents did not approve the decision to send 450 extra troops to Iraq. Of the respondents who are Liberal party voters, 0,18% approved the decision to send an extra 450 troops to Iraq. Assume that, of the people surveyed, 0,84 % were not Liberal party voters. One Australian is selected randomly.

a)  What is the probability that the person is not a Liberal party voter and approves the decision to send an extra 450 troops to Iraq?

b)  What is the probability that the person is not a Liberal party voter or disapproves the decision to send an extra 450 troops to Iraq?

Comment: The numbers seem wildly off, even bizarre, since 0.18% is about 1/550 (for a typical sized poll that would be *two people* -- you can't imply you 'know' the probability from two  "approve" answers) and 0.84% is about 1/120 (maybe 8-10 people in a typical poll). Do you mean 18% and 84% instead? (i.e. 0.18 and 0.84 as proportions; the second percentage is twice too high to be the actual figure but at least a believable alteration to reality to make a question).

Comment: If you assume the only possibilities are approve or oppose (which is rarely the case), there are enough pieces of information in the question. HOWEVER, there seems to be a consistency problem with the proportions. I'm double checking, but please confirm your numbers.

Comment: By way of comparison, the actual proportions in that poll (yes, I went and found the real figures for the March 2005 Morgan Poll on the question of the 450 troops) were overall 63% oppose, 32% approve and 5% don't know and 51% of LNP voters approve (that is either voters for the Liberal party or their close coalition partners, the National party). [The typical proportion of self-identified coalition voters on a 'two party preferred' basis would be roughly 50% and the Liberal vote is likely around 80% of that - about 40% of the total.]

Comment: On the consistency issue - if the intended figures are 85%, 18% and 84%, and "approve" and "oppose" the only options, then 18% is too high a proportion of 84% to have 15% overall approval (18% of 84% implies a lower bound of 15.12% overall). That problem doesn't occur with 0.85%, 0.18% and 0.84% ... but you seem to run into problems elsewhere in the table.

Answer (score 1):

As @Glen_b pointed out, the figures look off. I am not going to use actual figures.

I am substituting $p_1$ for $0.85\%$ and $p_2$ for $0.18\%$ and $84\%$ by $p_3$. Let the variable $L$ stand for Liberal party voter. Thus, $L=0$ means he is not a Liberal party voter and $L=1$ means he is. Similarly, let $D=0$ mean does not approve and $D=1$ mean he does approve sending extra troops. Therefore we get,

$P(D=0) = p_1$ and $P(D=1) = 1-p_1$

$P(D=1|L=1) = p_2$ and $P(D=0|L=1) = 1-p_2$

$P(L=0) = p_3$ and $P(L=1) = 1 - p_3$

a) Asks for $ P(L=0 , D=1 ) = P(L=0|D=1)*P(D=1) = (1-P(L=1|D=1))P(D=1) = (1-\frac{P(D=1|L=1)*P(L=1)}{P(D=1)})*P(D=1)$

All these values are known

b)$P(L=0 \text{ or } D=0) = P(L=0) + P (D=0) - P(L=0,D=0) = P(L=0) + P (D=0) - P(L=0|D=0)P(D=0) = P(L=0) + P (D=0) - (1-P(L=1|D=0))P(D=0) =  P(L=0) + P (D=0) - (1 - \frac{P(D=0|L=1)P(L=1)}{P(D=0)})P(D=0)$

Again you know all these values

Comment: @Glen_b will keep that in mind